# Dumping term in equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, elasticity, viscosity, structural-beam

I want to know the physical interpretation of the term $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {g(s){\psi _{xx}}(x,t - s)ds}$$ in some equation. This term is called infinite memory and the function $g$ is called relaxation function. What is the difference between this term and the same term replacing $\infty $ by $t$? This term can be found in Temoshinko system or Von Karman system. Is there any relation between this term and viscoelasticity ? Thanks.

Comment: A link to a source that uses this function would be useful.

Comment: Give the whole equation.

Comment: infinite memory in math http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X11004203

Answer (score 0):

Ok....I considered the system $45$ in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226141203_Asymptotic_limits_and_stabilization_for_the_1D_nonlinear_Mindlin-Timoshenko_system
 with replacing ${\psi _t}$ by $\int\limits_0^\infty  {g(s){\psi _{xxxx}}(x,t - s)ds}$  and I added a delay terms to the second equation... [image]

You can see the memory terms in the paper above in comment.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $\psi$ were the stress tensor, then the integral would represent the strain at time t in a viscoelastic fluid, in which the stress had been changing with time, and where g is the creep compliance.  A viscoelastic fluid has a memory not only for the present state of stress (as for a purely elastic solid), but for the entire past history of the state of stress.  The equation would apply to a linearly viscoelastic material (at small strains).  For a viscoelastic fluid, an equation of this same form can also be used to calculate the stress at time t as a function of the history of the rate of deformation; in this case, g would represent the stress relaxation function.

Comment: Sir another question is in my mind...what is the phisical difference between finite and infinite memory ?  Thank you sir for your reaction...

Comment: Viscoelastic materials have fading memory, and tend to remember the more recent past more than the distant past.  However, there are certainly viscoelastic solids that remember the initial undeformed state forever.